# Is there a way to remove the shadow on the bottom launcher?

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

When I change the launcher position to bottom, I get this ugly shadow:

[image]

I have tried googling this for ages and I found nothing, I have also tried making several images from /usr/share/unity/icons (./launcher_pressure_effect.png,launcher_pressure_effect_rotated.png)  transparent but that didn't work either. Is there any way to remove this?